# Scaling down paths/elements on an svg with very high coordinates that have many decimal points

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

Let's say you have a list of coordinates like so:
`2942852.602193035 472992.4195375803`
How would you go about scaling these down so that they fit in an svg. Coordinates like `294.2852602193035 472.9924195375803` would fit, but scaling my lines to (.0001) with the scale property on my lines doesnt seem to work.  It is fairly intricate linework.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Here's where you can check out some code:
https://snack.expo.io/_-0M6dRP5

```
     <Svg
  height="1920"
  width="1080"
  fill="none"
  viewBox="294.2852602193035 472.9924195375803 897.8977111047134 1329.2074627304683"
  preserveAspectRatio='none'>
        {//this rectangle shows up }
        <Rect x="294.285534094599" y="472.6193465770291" width="300" height="300"
        fill="blue" onPress={()=>{alert('achoo!')}}/> 
        {//this one doesn't, even without the transform matrix}
        <G transform="matrix(1,0,0,-1,0,0)" scale="0.0001">
            <Rect x="2942855.34094599" y="472619.3465770291" width="300" height="300"
               fill="red" onPress={()=>{alert('achoo!')}}/> 
        </G>

</Svg>
```

Comment: You can either use viewBox or put your elements under g with transform(scale(0.0001)) - both methods should work

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky Hi Michael, thank you for your comment.  Unfortunately I can not use viewbox (limitation with the library I'm using) and like I said in my question, using the transform property to scale by 0.0001 does not work. I have updated my question with a working example

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "doesn't seem to work"?

Comment: @MarkusZeller Doesnt show up on the screen

Comment: transform="scale(0.0001)" i.e. scale is not a valid attribute on its own.

Comment: @RobertLongson can you point me to where i can learn how to use it effectively?

Comment: Either the [SVG specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/coords.html#TransformAttribute) or the [SVG primer](https://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/IG/resources/svgprimer.html#operations)